# How do I deal with answers that are good for experienced users but potentially dangerous for newbies?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm not really experienced with Git and I had a problem exactly as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2941517/57428). Note that all of the four answers mention `git reset --hard` **which causes loss of uncommitted/unstashed changes in the working copy** and [only one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941524/57428) actually mentions the risk of data loss and only does so somewhere closer to the bottom.

Since I'm not really experienced with Git I'd say that it's not immediately obvious that the command sequences mentioned in the answers can actually cause data loss. Maybe it's obvious for experienced users - I don't know. I feel like every answer advising on such command sequences deserves a clear warning in the beginning (unless the question was something like "how do I have all the data on my disk deleted?" - then of course it's obvious that any command sequence provided as an answer can cause a data loss).

So I'm pretty sure those answers Need Improvement™. What should I do? Should I edit them and include a warning? Should I do anything else?

Comment: I would leave a comment, suggesting that the author of the answer add a warning.

Comment: **A lot of people will leave a comment in big bold text like this that says WARNING: THIS WILL REMOVE CHANGES FROM YOUR WORKING COPY**.

Answer (score 8):

I spend most of my time in the Git tag. On a lot of answers I see that involve `git reset`, I will often see people leaving bold comments like

> **WARNING: HARD RESETS UNDO MODIFIED FILES IN THE WORKING COPY**

if it's not already mentioned in the answer.

### Update

I've just edited all the answers that mention using a hard reset with a warning about losing any uncommitted modifications.