# The Impact of Information Sources on Code Security

Tags: discussion, security

According to the [highly decorated](https://cps-vo.org/group/sos/papercompetition) paper [The Impact of Information Sources on Code Security](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7546508)

> Internet resources such as Stack Overflow are blamed for promoting insecure solutions that are naively copy-pasted by inexperienced developers

Does this mean we should do something about it or is it all the developers fault?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293930/problematic-php-cryptography-advice-in-popular-questions

Comment: Have you read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339344/editing-of-insecure-code-examples) or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348946/poorly-worded-8-year-old-question-with-hundreds-of-votes-and-security-implicatio) or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273058/flag-posts-with-security-issues?rq=1)? I think I remember a question about a security warning that has been posted not that long ago.

Comment: We shouldn't change anything. Insecure coding approaches will almost always be accompanied by at least one comment pointing that out. If a user can't be bothered to read the comments before using a piece of code, there's nothing we can do to help them.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Due to the always vehemently statement that comments are not that important on SO (second class citizens) I have my doubts :)

Comment: It's true that SO's policy of comments being second class citizens is ridiculous at times. That said, I don't think it's common for moderators to remove comments pointing out security problems.

Comment: Last time I checked there wasn't a banner on the site that said: *find your insecure solutions here* so I'm not sure what kind of promoting that is? Employing inexperienced developers that are tasked with writing code that is security critical  is worth  a few papers. I'll decorate them myself if needed ...

Comment: I think there's an interesting assumption here that the guy who copies and pasts from SO would suddenly become the model of security conscientiousness if he were only forced to write the code himself.

Comment: Lets say we do put up some kind of banner warning people that a particular example "isn't secure". What then? that doesn't stop the user that would have copied and pasted it without thinking about it from still doing it. The problem still lies with the developer looking for a solution. Who decides which answers get this banner?

Comment: @Pekka웃 This has come to my mind on more than one occasion.  An answer that gains an overwhelming number of upvotes because of google searches its copy-and-paste-ability may well benefit from at least a comment clearly stating "Warning: this answer is highly vulnerable to SQL injection".  You can't stop someone from using it, but it could be taken as a flaw in the Q&A system for such answers to hit the top with no explicit indications of something being off about them.

Comment: Hmm, this is specifically about the [android] tag.  They could have saved the effort to do the study, we already knew.

Comment: @rene there better be bows and ribbons

Comment: A strange paper. It has an very general purpose title, but immediately boils down to being specifically about Android app code. I find that very strange, the problems are the same for any environment where application code runs directly on a client machine with direct access to both the internet and critical data. Its almost like it is written to specifically associate Android with insecurity. And then it uses wonky arguments like there being lots of insecure answers on "forums like Stack Overflow" as ammunition... Ugh.

Answer (score 17):

No, ***we*** don't have to change a thing.  The developer copying and pasting code blindly from here, or the company that permits that thing to happen, is the entity that needs to change.

The article appears to be shifting blame from the people actually responsible for the software's implementation and security onto others who are only really trying to help.  It's really not our place to say whether or not the examples we provide will reliably work in the secure environments you require, and any advice taken from here *needs* to be done so with security in the back of one's mind.

If the developer copying code from here can't do that...there's little we can do to warn them of *anything* security-related, really.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think we have to change anything systematically. That study was conducted in a fairly controlled environment. There were four groups of developers solving the same problems. Three of the groups were restricted to using **only one resource** (the official documentation, Stack Overflow, or two books that were provided). There was also a fourth group that was allowed to choose the resource they thought was best (which I think is how most people actually code).

The results of the study show that people in the Book and Stack Overflow groups performed best at getting their code to work, but the Stack Overflow group produced significantly less secure code than the other groups.

But the study goes on to say the following (emphasis added):

> We also asked about the effect of participants' assigned resource on their performance. In every non-free condition, the large majority (official: 92.3% (12/13); book: 92.9% (13/14); SO: 78.6% (11/14)) said they would have performed better on the tasks if they had been allowed to use different resources. In particular, official and book participants said they would have liked to access Stack Overflow or search engines such as Google, so that they could search for their specific problems rather than reading background information. One book user mentioned the “danger that books could be outdated.” On the other hand, **many SO participants said they would have liked to access the official documentation to read up on background information for their problems**.

So it looks like people are already aware that they shouldn't rely solely on code they found on Stack Overflow, even when they get things working. Given a choice, they'd refer to the documentation in addition to Stack Overflow.

That's not to say that we *shouldn't* do anything. If you see a highly-upvoted, accepted answer that's out of date, definitely feel free to provide a better answer, or at least post a link to the documentation in the comments. If I take anything away from that study, it's that making secure code *easier* is the best way to make sure people actually write secure code.