# Where's the line between spam/advertisment and showing resources or demos?

Tags: discussion, spam, self-promotion

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501243/how-to-prevent-google-maps-flyout-from-reappearing-upon-resize-after-flyout-is-c) just now and want to get some feedback on following question that arose while reading the article/question:

Is it already some sort of advertisement when the OP states in the first sentence

> Im a very novice programmer but created a cool Google Maps flyout which is a hybrid of several online tutorials..

and then links to a specific site on two occasions for other users to reproduce his problem?

What are your opinions on that specific case? Is this already some sort of spam or fully acceptable in this case?

You may take following facts into consideration: The user has posted [three questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5498556/stuart?tab=questions) in total - all three with negative voting record ([1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498522/how-to-prevent-navigation-menu-from-leaving-visible-portion-of-screen), [2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550310/background-image-is-not-properly-scaling-to-parent-container), [3rd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501243/how-to-prevent-google-maps-flyout-from-reappearing-upon-resize-after-flyout-is-c)) and all three mentioning a certain website leaving a fishy smell of repeat offender.

To answer Goerge Jemptys question in the comments below why nobody marked this as a dupe besides him:

This is not a dupe of [What is the exact definition of “spam” for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow) because I try to get opinions on a very **specific case** here..

Comment: One suggestion I may give: don't give upvotes to counter downvotes. give upvotes because you think the question is good, helpful, useful. If the question is really below standards, you've just made it a positive rep gain for the OP....  As for "is it SPAM".... hmmm I'd say no. I don't see it much like advertisement honestly. It is noise though, and doesn't really have its place in the question

Comment: I can still revoke it in case the common consens of this community discusssion is that it's some sort of spam/advertisment - that's why I'm actually asking this question here ;) Since the question is of a somhow medium to good quality an upvote would be still valid

Comment: No you can't *always* revoke. The vote eventually locks and becomes impossible to change, unless the question gets edited.

Comment: I had a similar question a while ago where a new user linked to his site. Magisch gave an answer which might give clarity in this situation as well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369190/9420984

Comment: @Patrice I know that, but this is why I'm having this discussion right now in order to get a consens in a timely manner before my revoke-option times-out ;)

Comment: Upvoting to counter downvotes is a misuse of the voting system.  You're voting on what others have done, not the content itself.

Comment: Isn't the revoke at 15 minutes? according to your comment, you upvoted 16 minutes ago. Your window is out already....

Comment: @Patrice : True that but after reading Magisch article mentioned above I believe thouh it's a little misplaced I dont think it was his intent to advertise and since the question is of ok-quality I left my vote as is..

Comment: @IluvLogix sure. My point was just that your intent of getting a consensus here in 15 minutes was a little bit optimistic :P. Your vote is your own to do with, of course. I was also just pointing out that "I'm giving you an upvote because you got downvoted" is a **very** different reasoning than "I give you an upvote cause I believe your question deserves one"

Comment: @Patrick : I fully agree with you there - maybe next time I shouldn't pack my reasons behind sarcasm such as `'to save your day'`.. But looking at the reaction of Stuart that just got deleted here on meta I think he ran out of humour anyways ;)

Comment: @yivi : Same here, that's why I asked - but let's see what common consens arises out of this discussion so we'll have a clearer picture on questions composed of such content - I agree on your comment that it looks kind of 'fishy'

Comment: Since JS is involved, it looks like the site is a live demo, on the same level as providing a JSFiddle (or related). There's still a MCVE requirement, but this question isn't exactly the first time a question links to off-site code.

Comment: @Zoe, While I agree that such links are often intended as a live demo of a problem, they are significantly worse than a link to a JSFiddle (both, as you said, still require a MCVE in the question). The site is almost certainly going to be updated once the OP gets an answer that works for them (from the OPs POV, that's the entire purpose of the question, after all). Thus, the link to their site has absolutely no lasting value for demonstrating the problem to future visitors. As far as the SO question goes, links to a live site only have value to the OP for solving their immediate problem.

Comment: *Do you have Developement problems? Do you want an instant answer to your code crap? Did you ever wished to find a website that solves your problems? Try to visit [this site](http://stackoverflow.com). It will solve all your problems.* - That's how spam looks to me. This question just seem to fail in providing a [mcve]. If it's his own website or JsFiddle doesn't matter. Simple lacks an MCVE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is just spam.  It's an advertisement for their own product, and isn't even asking a question.  The entire purpose of the post is to draw traffic to their own product.  That's *by definition* spam.

The fact that they've made a pattern of behavior of this makes it even worse, with all of their posts linking out to their site.  That would qualify the posts as spam even if they were asking good questions (which they aren't).

> Avoid overt self-promotion.
>
> [...]
>
> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free community promotion ads for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Not sure I quite agree with it being spam.  Seems more like a new user that just doesn't understand how we do things here.

Comment: @yivi or it could be [SODD](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361904/what-is-stack-overflow-driven-development)

Comment: @Suraj Truth be told, it looks more misguided than ill-intended to me. But still, maybe they could rethink their approach.

Comment: This assumes motives without evidence. While I have no problem with deleting the posts and giving the user a good talking to, the posts are at face value *asking programming questions*. The fact the user chose to ask specifically about their production site does not negate that they are demonstrably presenting us with HTML/CSS/JS problems to solve. Quite probably poorly asked, downvote and close worthy ones, but this is a far cry from the obvious, straightforward, pure self-promotion your answer asserts. This answer deserves to be downvoted to oblivion for blatantly misrepresenting the facts.

Comment: @jpmc26 agreed - if the developer is only working on one specific product, of course all of their questions will be related to it. I don't see why the links couldn't simply be removed while leaving the questions with code intact. And yes there are a couple of ads on the website but targeting a dev Q&A site with spam for a series of motocross events (which make most of their revenue by attendance) doesn't seem very efficient

Comment: @jpmc26 It doesn't really need to assume motive at all.  Constantly linking out to your own site in every post of yours is defined as spam even if you *are* asking good questions (which they aren't).  Also *lots* of spammers learned to tack on something vaguely resembling a half hearted question/answer into their posts to try to avoid them being removed as spam, it's not new, and it doesn't make it not spam.

Comment: @Servy No. The entire section you cite is called "**Avoid overt self-promotion.**" There is plenty of evidence that the user is not linking their site to promote it but just to demonstrate the problem. The paragraph you cite is just clearly not talking about what this user is doing by any reasonable interpretation. You're just trying to be pedantic, but it doesn't work if you actually stop and think for 10 seconds about what the help page is saying and compare it to what's happening here. Your answer *explicitly* asserts that the user is intentionally advertising.

Comment: This is clearly not spam; all it takes is reading the flag description for spam to know that. Even moreso to me since I have additional context. Answer incoming.

Comment: @jpmc26 "Here are some specific behaviors to avoid - **even with the best of intentions, these will nearly always result in your posts being flagged as spam**: [...] Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much. [...] Don't include links except to support what you've written. [...]"  The help center *very specifically* says that these actions, which the OP has engaged in, will be treated as spam *even if they are well intentioned*.  So you saying that it's not spam because it's well intentioned specifically contradicts the help center.

Comment: @TylerH They're literally doing exactly what the help center says qualifies as spam.

Comment: @Servy Saying that something draws spam flags in practice is not saying that something *is* spam. Your answer explicitly asserts that it is spam. Those are completely different statements. And wherever you pulled that from is not linked in your answer. If you're gonna be pedantic, at least do it right and interpret statements correctly.

Comment: @jpmc26 I think it's pretty safe to say that the help center is referring to merited spam flags, rather than describing things that will be incorrectly flagged as spam.  The whole section is on how to not be a spammer, and it suggests not doing those things because it'll result in your posts being flagged as spam.  Why would it say those things if it didn't consider them to actually be spam?  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) is the page.

Comment: @Servy "I think it's pretty safe to say that the help center is referring to merited spam flags..." I have no idea how you justify that when the entire page is about how to promote your own work without *being perceived* as a spammer *by the community*, when the user is clearly not promoting their work but *asking about specific problems they're having with it*. That entire page is also talking about writing answers that use your product rather than questions about an actual site, so there's an obvious gap you've failed to close here.

Comment: @Servy the help center being written with the knowledge of user habits does not make those user habits correct. The system says users will flag such things as spam. But the system also says *via the spam flag* that such things are not spam. So here we have the system revealing that users often wrongly flag stuff as spam and you're using *that* to justify your argument? Your evidence is arguing the opposite of your position.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, the entire page is about how to avoid your post being considered spam *justifiably* by the community.  The page focuses on answers because most inappropriate self promotion is posted as answers, not questions.  That doesn't mean you can promote as much, and however you want, in questions.

Comment: @TylerH The fact that a one sentence description of the flag isn't able to cover the nuance and less frequent situations as the more detailed page doesn't mean that everything covered in the more detailed page about *what qualifies as spam* is actually wrong and that we should do the opposite of what *the help center specifically tells people to do*.  The help center says that to not be a spammer you shouldn't be constantly posting links to your product, and that *it will be treated as spam if you do that*.  That doesn't make it not spam, it makes it *unambiguously spam*.

Comment: @Servy, No, "users will likely treat this as spam" means users will likely treat it as spam. It doesn't mean it is spam. If you would like the flag description to be amended/improved, file a [meta-tag:feature-request]. In the meantime, as I've previously recommended, please don't expect users to rely on your headcanon when it so starkly differs from reality.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not suggesting that the one sentence description of the flag be amended to include the entire page description of what spam is just because people like you want to ignore the detailed description just because the one sentence description doesn't cover it.  That doesn't make it my headcannon, it makes it *what the help center specifically says is spam, and how to respond to it*.  That you refuse to follow the help center's guidelines just because you don't like them doesn't mean other people are going to do the same.

Answer (score 18):

Let's get this out of the way first: the questions are bad. They lack a self-enclosed MCVE and expect people to delve into code on a 3rd party website (that is clearly destined for production after it gets out of the test phase). This is reason enough to downvote, close vote, and delete vote by itself.

That said, there's some things that are *good* in the questions, too. Let's look at one paragraph from one of the questions:

> In summary: background-image wont properly scale within parent container. Secondly, (which I believe is probably related) Why the big empty space between the divs going down the page?

This demonstrates the following positive qualities:

- On topic programming problems involving specific elements of HTML and CSS
- Effort attempting to understand, diagnose, and fix the problem themselves
- Scoped to a narrow behavior of the page (There's a small addendum about something they believe is related which might warrant a second question, but it isn't some huge diatribe about a totally separate problem.)
- Description of current behavior vs. desired behavior

The questions overall have a similar level of quality, which isn't high but is far from the worst posts I've seen.

The fact that the question is obviously basically on topic makes it clear enough that we have no reason to suspect ill intentions here. The user clearly misunderstands our normal practices and expectations, but I see not a single line of evidence that their primarily motive is to get traffic to their site. They even offer the following poor excuse for why they didn't include an MCVE:

> Would be way too cluttered for something someone can easily see via the above link.

This doesn't excuse them, of course, but it offers a believable explanation for why they're linking to the site. There is no reason to believe that the primary motivation for linking was to get traffic to their site.

So what do we do about it? Downvote, close vote, delete vote as normal. Flag for moderator attention since there's a problem pattern here, and moderators probably need to communicate that self hosting example code rather than putting it in the question is not acceptable. (Make it custom so you can explain the pattern.) Maybe point out the existence of the snippet feature. But putting aside any technicalities about what is and is not spam, these questions do not warrant losing 100 reputation per post. On the contrary, the good things (*especially* the increasingly rare demonstration of effort) I do see encourage me to think that with some education, they could eventually become a productive member of the community.

(Granted, their deleted reaction here pretty much wipes away that encouragement, but my answer is about the questions linked, not the user.)

Answer (score 11):

I try and look at everything in good faith, and to me this doesn't seem like spam.

As [Magisch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369190/1873567) says in this excellent answer to a similar question:

> Outwardly, it doesn't look like the intent of the post is to promote a product or service. Outwardly, it looks just like a low quality question of someone trying to embed an iframe into his website and not providing any of the necessary steps for SO to help them (MCVE, their code, what they tried, etc).
>
> I'm not sure I'd flag this as spam. Assuming good faith it's probably just a low quality question. That only marginally changes how it should be treated anyways. As it's currently sitting at -2 and is well on track to being closed, the question is most likely going to suffer automatic deletion in due time.

The question in cases here seems to be about preventing a flyout reappearing, it has what possibly is the relevant code, and then links to his website so you can see the issue live, and most importantly, links to the JavaScript files (which no normally spammer would bother doing).

The OP of this post is not exactly helping their cause, but taking the post in isolation it does not seem to be spam to me. And spammers usually don't hang around once they've posted either.

And as to them posting a lot of links to their website (3 questions with links), I agree with [Suraj Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377143/wheres-the-border-between-spam-advertisment-and-showing-resources-or-demos/377146#comment650727_377145) in that it's a case of [SODD](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361904/what-is-stack-overflow-driven-development).

Comment: I'm appalled by the number of downvotes on this factually correct answer. There's no evidence of malicious intent.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, I saw it. But why on Earth is that an excuse to downvote a correct answer and upvote one that blatantly lies about the situation? Also, I don't equate "unnecessarily angry reaction" with "malicious intent" in the first place.

Comment: don't try to reason an angry mob.

Answer (score 5):

Bit late to the game here as OP has already responded and the linked Qs have all been closed/deleted, but I have interacted with this user several times on chat and am perhaps more informed than the other respondents here, and the accepted answer especially is flat out wrong and harmfully fails to assume good faith.

To me, this is clearly not spam. That should be evident even to others who don't have the history I have with OP, as the spam flag says:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

OP here is not trying to promote their product... at least not as a primary effort. His primary effort is trying to get help with web programming problems for his website/webapp(s). He also clearly indicates they are his sites and apps, so there's no affiliation problem, either.

What these *are* are good examples of "lacks MCVE" closure candidates. I tried [via an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46552673/2756409) (10k only) and via several discussions in the HTML/CSS/Web Design chat room (going back years) to get him to include MCVEs in his posts and his chats to get better help and to potentially discover his own problems (e.g. narrowing down to an MCVE might reveal the issue to him), but he so far has seemed either uninterested in doing so or perhaps incapable. I believe the folks over at room 17 have also encountered him a few times.

As most respondents have said, these questions should be closed with the "Lacks MCVE" reason until the user learns to abide by the rules and expectations of the site. I know I have certainly given him plenty of benefit of the doubt in the past; you've linked three questions, but he has many more that he has deleted in the past, and from my recollection none of them included MCVEs.

Comment: Constantly linking out to one's own affiliated site in every single one of their numerous posts *is defined as spam in the help center*, as my answer states.  Additionally, that they've made a constant habit of *intentionally refusing* to provide self contained answers, and are instead *demanding* that anyone who wants to understand the question go to their site, driving it traffic, only *supports* the assertion that it's spam.  That's not a suggestion that it's *not* spam.  **Demanding** that people go to a website you own to even understand the question is *super* spammy.

Comment: @Servy Nothing you've cited explicitly defines spam at all. All of it focuses on answers rather than questions, too.

Comment: @Servy it's clear you don't know what spam means. Demanding someone go to your site to understand the question is not spam. Spam is unsolicited advertising. This is not unsolicited, it is in pursuit of programming help. The user has unreasonable demands/requests, yes. The user posts off-topic/close-worthy questions, yes. The user does not spam by the site's definition of it. The quicker you realize that, the quicker we can all get on with helping users.

Comment: @jpmc26 That doesn't mean it doesn't apply to questions, it just means that most people who engage in these activities are often posting answers, not question.  And  yes, it *does* specifically say that constantly referring to your own affiliated site is spam, even if you disclose affiliation, and even if there's an actual post in there.

Comment: @Servy It also talks about *advertising rates*, which is clearly *not* relevant to a user asking about specific programming problems. None of it is talking about a situation remotely like this one. It's clearly talking about *using the site to bring attention to your own*, which is the definition of spam that appears elsewhere and is **evidently not what is going on here**.

Comment: @TylerH It's clear that you don't know what spam means. Constantly demanding that people to to your site to even understand your question is spam.  Spam is inappropriate promotion of a product.  This is inappropriate promotion of a product.  That there's a very low quality programming question in there doesn't change that, as the help center makes very clear.  The user is spamming by the site's definition of it.  The quicker you realize that, the quicker we can all get on with helping users.

Comment: @jpmc26 How does the fact that it mentions advertising rates mean it doesn't apply to specific programming problems?  Its' specifically saying that even if there's an appropriate post in there, constantly including references to your own product *is still spam*, and that you should be avoiding that *even if posting otherwise appropriate posts* (which they're also not doing).  It very explicitly says that there being a real post in there, in addition to the promotion, doesn't mean it's not spam.  It's describing *exactly* this situation.

Comment: @Servy **Because it's asserting that there is good reason to believe the person described is motivated by a desire to advertise their product.** In *this* situation, **all** the evidence points to that *not* being the case.

Comment: @Servy Parroting my own words back and repeating yourself is immature and doesn't help the fact that you're wrong. Perhaps the core issue here is that you are not aware *you should be assuming good faith in all situations*. Pretty much everyone who has responded here and in the linked answer in the comments sees this as not spam, but a misguided effort at getting programming help. You seem to think that, regardless of everything, OP must be covertly trying to drive traffic to his site for dubious/illicit reasons. You cannot moderate in isolation; context is key.

Comment: @jpmc26 You're assuming that.  In fact it explicitly states, with no room for ambiguity at all, that *even if you have good intentions* that's still spam.  There's no possible room to assume that the help center is only about cases where you can assume an intention to advertise when it *explicitly and unambiguously says that it's still spam even if there's good intentions*.  The help center *specifically* says that's wrong, and I've quoted it to you before.

Comment: @Servy **It doesn't say that.** It only *explicitly* says it might get flagged as spam by the community and provides advice about conventions we have to avoid that happening. Self promotion is actually explicitly *allowed* by the help you link, since it describes the ways in which to do it without getting in trouble. And these questions *aren't even self promotion*.

Comment: @TylerH You seemed to think that just repeatedly asserting that you're right, despite the help center specifically contradicting you, was a good thing to do.  I showed you how immature that approach is.  As I've said before, *the intentions are irrelevant*.  The content is defined by the help center as spam even if there *is* good intentions.  They *still* need to correct their behavior.  And them being told that what they're doing is wrong, and continuing to do it anyway, is not demonstrating good intentions.  That, and their behavior here on meta, very clearly demonstrates poor intentions.

Comment: @TylerH "You seem to think that, regardless of everything, OP must be covertly trying to drive traffic to his site for dubious/illicit reasons." Actually I've said numerous times that *their intentions are irrelevant*, and that the behavior is spam *even if they have good intentions*.  I've very specifically avoided even theorizing about their intentions in the linking because *it just doesn't matter*, it's spam either way.

Comment: @Servy I haven't "repeatedly asserted" I'm right; I've shown via several different explanations and examples how you're wrong. There's a difference. By the way, since you seem so interested in absolutist positions (albeit wrong absolutist positions), the https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion page is about answers, not questions, so you shouldn't be using it to support anything in this topic, since we're talking about questions.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, the help center describes ways you can self promote appropriately, without it being spam. **And they didn't do that**, they did tons and tons of things that it says make it spam.  And they were told not to do those things, and they kept doing them anyway, because they just *didn't care*.  That makes these questions inappropriate self promotion, a.k.a. spam.

Comment: @TylerH Really?  You're honestly going to tell me that self promotion is only inappropriate in answers, and that self promotion is entirely appropriate without restriction or consequence in questions, just because the help center topic about it focuses on answers as the *vast* majority of self promotion is posted as answers?  I think it's pretty safe to say that what's there is applicable to any type of post.  This is further supported by the quote in my answer, which refers to all posts.

Comment: @Servy I'm not the one here saying only 1% of the situation is relevant. If you want to consider a broader application of the rules, that would be great and I readily welcome it! In the meantime, please consider reading the help center and posts you reply to more carefully in the future so as not to make abjectly false claims, and also remember to **assume good faith**; if intent were actually so irrelevant, then the Code of Conduct wouldn't stress that *in bold*. Finally, inappropriate self-promotion is not spam. Spam is explicitly and unambiguously (to use your words) defined in my answer.

Comment: @Servy Post Script - the quote in your answer actually comes from either the page I linked to or Expected Behavior page, both of which talk about spam exclusively (at least explicitly) with regard to answers, not questions.

Comment: @TylerH You should take your own advice and actually read the help center, rather than making statements that contradict it, and say that *exact quotes from the help center* are wrong.  The help center *defines* self promotion like this as spam.  The definition in your answer is an incomplete summary, for the sake of brevity.  The detailed description I linked to *specifically* defines this behavior as spam.  It *specifically* says that the intentions are irrelevant, and that the content is spam *even if there are good intentions*, so even if you assume good intentions, **it's still spam**.

Comment: @TylerH those pages *focus* on answers, because most of the spam of that variety is posted as answers.  In some of the more general guidelines on those pages it refers to posts, not just answers, as well, and most of the content is applicable to both.  If you're seriously saying that self promotion in any way, shape, or form, is appropriate in questions, and not answers, just because the help center focuses on answers, then that doesn't sound like acting in good

Comment: @Servy: I'm just chiming in because there are so many comments here. The three questions *are not spam*. They are just bad questions. He simply hosts his MCVE on his website for his own convenience, when he should be hosting it on JSFiddle (etc.) and also including the code in the question. There's nothing more to it than that. Being marked as spam gives -100 reputation and should be reserved for cases where there is minimal doubt.

Comment: @thirtydot And yet the spam guidelines *specifically* say that that behavior is spam.  So yes, it is spam.  There is no doubt.  The user knows the behavior is inappropriate.  They've been told it's inappropriate.  They keep doing it.  That there are consequences for them intentionally breaking the rules and posting spam is not a bad thing.  It's why they're there.

Comment: @Servy: I think you're wrong on this one, but it seems that none of us can change your mind. [The guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) do not even support your position. "Don't include links except to support what you've written." - the links in his questions clearly support his (bad) questions. Here's another way of looking at it: one of his questions is still there, and hasn't been deleted as spam. For spam: [I know it when I see it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it). And that isn't it. Good day, sir.

Comment: @thirtydot How do the guidelines not support what I've written?  Not only has the user violated *numerous* guidelines on that page, but they've even broken the one that you've quoted.  The links weren't "supporting what was written", they were *the entirety of the question*.  Links are supposed to be ancillary; not necessary in order to understand the post.  That's not the case here.  Literally *all* of the user's questions were deleted, one was recently undeleted by people like you who are blatantly ignoring the rules for improper promotion.  That doesn't mean it isn't.

Comment: @Servy Literally all of the comments by me, jpmc26, and now thirtydot to you on this page have described the ways in which the guidelines do not support what you've written. Everyone who has spoken up on this meta question in answers and comments agrees this isn't spam... except you. Even the two moderators who have engaged with Stuart's question(s) don't think they're spam. As a matter of fact, the one question that *was* deleted as an alleged spam question is the one that was undeleted. The other two were deleted for other reasons, e.g. low quality, no MCVE, and/or no value to readers.

Comment: @Servy So you can continue to accuse the overwhelming majority of participants in this discussion and multiple moderators of intentional misuse/abuse of the system if you like, but the rest of us have come to the correct conclusion and moved on.

Comment: @TylerH Several people just saying they don't care what the help center says and that this isn't spam because they say so doesn't make you right.  The help center *very specifically* explains what type of self promotion isn't appropriate.  This user did those things.  You may not like it, but that doesn't make it not spam.  The actual votes on posts show that this a controversial opinion.  That 3 people decided to repeat the same arguments instead of voting on other's saying the same thing, while those agreeing with me just voted, doesn't mean I'm the only one with my opinion.