# What practical and reasonable options does the community have in order to avoid (if desired) the so called 'meta effect'?

Tags: discussion, meta-effect

I recently [searched here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=possibilities+to+avoid+meta+effect) for possibilities to avoid the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) and couldn't find any articles that would address/contain reasonable proposals.

So here's, or rather are my question(s):

Is the meta-effect **desirable** in terms of drawing necessary attention to a post even if it sometimes (regarding on the readers personal point of view on that topic) results in licentious negative-voting that otherwise wouldn't have happened to such an extent?

Or is it actually **not desired** by the SO community since it's unbalanced relation regarding down-votes?

In case of the latter, what proposals (like using an excerpt without directly identifying the post or poster via a link) would be reasonable and also effective to avoid this?

I personally don't believe this is a duplicate of [Impose a 24h voting freeze..](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta) since I'm asking here if this effect is desirable/undesirable. In addition I don't present a certain proposal to avoid the meta effect - I asked the community for proposals in general if the latter is the common consensus.

Comment: The logic is that the meta effect simply causes a question to go to its "final state" faster. Good questions get upvotes faster. Bad questions get their downvotes/closure faster.  Personally (and I know a couple of other users that say they do it as well) I try not to vote on anything I see when clicking on a link from meta.

Comment: I think that the only reasonable way to avoid the meta effect is to include screenshots of the relevant post(s) with the titles and usernames blacked out (as opposed to full screenshots or links). It is still possible to find the post(s) that the question is referring to, but that mild barrier to finding them might be enough to dissuade the meta mob from hounding any given post with votes and flags.

Comment: @Patrice Good point there on the "final state" - but there's still the effect that the amount of downvotes exceeds the regular/ordinary..

Comment: "exceeds the regular/ordinary"? Since I'm sure you won't write that without any evidence except your "gut feeling", can you please share that? Thanks.

Comment: @Tom Eyperienced it yesterday when [posting this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377143/wheres-the-line-between-spam-advertisment-and-showing-resources-or-demos) on meta when poor Stuart got down-votes exceeding the ordinary for that given time frame - besides that you could read the answer of Oded (>400k rep) on the question I linked in my post

Comment: One thing about "ordinary" though. The number of views also grows very quickly when something is linked in meta. Is it possible it's that effect we see more than "out of the ordinary downvote". Basically "do questions linked on meta get so much visibility that the up/down vote ratio (compared to views) is still similar to what we see on non-meta linked questions?"

Comment: @Patrice  Interesting - Are there any statistics available in order to get the relevant numbers to determine the aspect ratio between those two?

Comment: @iLuvLogix I guess you can make it in some SEDE queries.... might be difficult to track which question has been linked from meta though

Comment: What do you mean with "ordinary"? More general votes than usual (up, down, close or delete votes) or votes "leaning" into a certain direction? About the first one: yes, that's obvious. You've shared a question to a much broader audience, thus more people will read the question and cast their vote. About the second one: it would be interesting to get some evidence regarding the negativity of the "meta effect". We (or at least I) don't know if the same amount of down votes (or the other types) were cast when the same people visited the question without being linked on meta.

Comment: I don't understand if you're looking for [something like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/), or are you looking for some sort of community consensus. If it's the latter, I'm afraid that kind of thing is very hard to achieve, if at all possible. I'm pretty sure a lot of users will have very different opinions about what's proper and what not about the meta-effect, or even opinions about [when is appropriate and when not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327134/). I believe that looking for consensus on this wold be a POB question.

Comment: @Tom With 'ordinary' I mean within the normal ratio of views and votes without being exposed on meta as Patrice mentioned in his comment as well

Comment: @yivi As stated in my question: 'In case of the latter....' - meaning that I'm curious if somebody comes up with a practical solution that could be used by sensible users of this community

Comment: I mean, you have more than one question _"is the ME good or bad"_ (POB), and _"how to avoid ME"_ which I think it's not possible to answer beyond _"if you want to avoid the meta-effect, avoid direct links, attempt to anonmyze if need to refer to specific posts"_.

Comment: @yivi Sometimes one question raises another - would you recommend to me to split them apart in seperate questions then?

Comment: The first question is completely POB, so I wouldn't ask it. I would refer to the many posts discussing the issue. The second question I find useless, since there is no magic about it: _if you want to avoid meta-effect when posting a question, try to make it less likely users can reach a specific post from your question._

Comment: And as you see on the answers below, users are answering _different questions_ in your post.

Comment: @yivi I disagree with respect to the POB point. We should be able to post Meta questions that probe whether there is a consensus about issues like this one

Comment: @duplode I understand, but I believe these questions are more harmful than beneficial. They are asked again, again, and again (just search for meta-effect and see the results), and the answers are all over the place. Some users will believe one thing, and others will believe another. In the end in most cases it will come to _"it depends"_, and those posts will be used now and then to attempt to "prove" a consensus exists, where it actually doesn't. Opinions change, members of the community change, circumstances change, etc.

Comment: @duplode In the end, either we have policy and tools (policy we kinda have, IMO, in the answer by Tim in the first question I linked), or it's all just a lot of noise.

Comment: @yivi Sorry if this reads like a caricature of your stance, but (1) Surely this can't mean we shouldn't discuss controversial issues about how the site is moderated? (2) If "either we have policy and tools [...] or it's all just a lot of noise", how should we decide whether new policies or new tools are necessary?

Comment: @yivi The question already has one close vote - if not for discussion what is meta exactly for?

Comment: @duplode It doesn't, dont' worry. I think is great to discuss interpretations of actual policy. In this case, it's not about site policy, but about etiquette. _"Should we, as end users,  do something to avoid the meta effect when posting on meta. If yes, what can we do?"_. I believe that's a mis of POB/Too Broad/Trivial; and it is also impossible to regulate. Another discussion would be _"Should SE/SO do something to avoid the meta effect"_ . That other question is a dupe. (It also doesn't help that this question is actually asking two different questions).

Comment: I don't think [licentious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/licentious) is quite the word you want, unless you are implying that people who downvote are sexual deviants...

Comment: generally you are right - but licentious can be also used in terms of 'with no restraint' or 'arbitrary' without the sexual connotation.. Feel free to edit ;)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for pointing that out - That remark just put a smile on  the frivolous part in me ;)

Comment: @yivi If you honestly consider this questions as noise  - why do you get involved with lots of comments on the actual content and the answers then? - That seems rather odd to me - Why not just vote for closure and move on..

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the noise by pointing out the uselesness of this question and questions like this.

Comment: @yivi Are you meta-policing a little too much here maybe? And still you are getting involved with comments like `I could understand attempting to avoid meta-effect in votes. But in flags...? Why?`and therefore aproove that this question is valid..

Comment: @iLuvLogix The fact that I believe the question is noise, ultimately harmful and should be closed doesn't preclude me for commenting on the question (to hopefully help you into editing into shape), or its answers (where they are perfectly relevant).

Comment: You are, instead of providing arugments against my points, making arguments against my participation.

Comment: not against your participation - but against your sentiment in regards to the validity of this question and the effort you undertake to point out your noise-thing.. And if you would read my comments you can see that i do indeed argue about the asked topic - but anyways - let everyone decide on their  own what to think about the topic and the question itself ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Impose a 24 hour voting freeze on questions being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta)

Comment: Does the "Hot Meta Posts" list cause a meta-meta (double meta?, meta^2) effect?  I never would have read or voted on this particular question without the list.  Is the list bad or good?  Should that list be eliminated?  The answer to all these questions is to stop visiting SO altogether and there won't be a problem to worry about.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley _I think that the only reasonable way to avoid the meta effect is to include screenshots of the relevant post(s)_ - ins't that effectively disenfranchising visual visually impaired users?

Comment: @user10465355 users who need accessibility tools obviously wouldn't be able to get much out of a screenshot, no (unless the image description was particularly thorough). That's a problem with all posts with images though. What do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley At the moment I am not convinced that any action is necessary, as the post shows no evidence that meta effect is significant enough (both in magnitude, as only tiny fraction of questions is ever discussed o meta, as well effect on votes ratio) compared to other non-organic sources of traffic.I could be wrong of course.

Comment: @user10465355 I just stumbled across a very good proposal suggested by JonK - [a non-interactive snapshot of the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269201/8230810). I concede, this is much better than an image if one were trying to avoid the meta effect.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley JonK's proposal is interesting and well-argued. One example of prior art along those lines is [Reddit's "no participation" mode](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoParticipation/wiki/intro). For many subreddits, using `np.reddit.com` rather than `www.reddit.com` when linking to a thread will disable the voting UI.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How does the Meta effect differ from sharing the link on Facebook, Twitter, or ?  I don't see anyone complaining about an influx of upvotes on their question.  This is specifically about the perceived additional negative attention a post receives via the audience engaged.

People see the Meta effect as a bad thing, because the end result generally is unfavorable to the advertised post.  Part of this is that the audience is much more quality minded, and usually have the additional privileges to perform curation activities, leading to the perceived negativity.  Nobody likes their question being closed, or downvoted.  Well, curators don't like low quality content; a question slipping through the cracks is arguably bad for the repository we're building.

There's going to be some additional commenting, which will lead to the user feeling harried.  That I believe is unfortunate; it's hard for people to refrain pitching in when they see an argument going on.  Here's the flip side, though; those comments often get defenders as well as detractors, which leads to a big massive freewheeling argument, where the defenders write off criticism, the poster sees the support and ignores criticism entirely, and the detractors just feel frustrated.  Everyone's better off just casting their votes and refusing to engage further.  That is, after all, their purpose.

TL;DR: Nobody complains about Facebook sharing and getting upvotes, but everybody complains about Meta sharing and being subject to curation.  Can't have one without the other.

Comment: IMHO you are comparing apples with oranges since not every FB or Twitter user has an SO-account and can therefore cast a vote.. Please also note that nobody is complaining about ME in this thread - I just asked a question (or two) how this effect is perceived..

Comment: @iLuvLogix And the ability to upvote comes much easier than the ability to downvote.  The chances of someone being able to upvote is much higher than downvote.  And I disagree with not complaining about it; your entire question is predicated on, "avoiding" the Meta effect, which carries the implication of it being a bad thing.

Comment: I composed the question title in the believe that it's a rather unfortunate effect after reading some articles on it - you used these words as well in your comment to James answer - but to clear my doubts on that topic I did ask if it's desirable or not..

Comment: @iLuvLogix There's an *aspect* of the meta effect I think is unfortunate.  It, however, isn't limited to only detractors.  I address that very aspect in my answer, and how we can properly deal with it.

Comment: "TL;DR: Nobody complains about Facebook sharing and getting upvotes" For the record, people do complain about those sometimes too, just not as much as the meta effect.  Of course it's usually not the author complaining about those upvotes, but rather other people who feel it's unfair or not representative of the post's quality or other such things.

Comment: @Servy It seems additional attention, no matter from where, causes *someone* to complain.  Meta effect, Facebook, social media, Hot Network Questions...

Comment: Technically, @iLuvLogix you can navigate meta without having an SO account as well...

Comment: @Patrice True but the affiliation between SO and meta is still much stronger than lets say SO and Twitter ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix 100% with you. I was just being pedantic ;)

Comment: @Patrice That's OK with me - what's a fact is a fact indeed ;)

Answer (score -4):

**Edit:** I don't have a horse in this race. I don't see the Meta Effect as a huge problem, but I can see why it is deemed to have issues. I don't see it as objectively or inherently desirable or undesirable. The below text addresses the following part of the question:

> what proposals (like using an excerpt without directly identifying the post or poster via a link) would be reasonable and also effective to avoid this?

---

I think that the only reasonable way to avoid the meta effect is to include screenshots of the relevant post(s) with the titles and usernames blacked out (as opposed to full screenshots or links).

It is still possible to find the post(s) that the question is referring to, but that mild barrier to finding them might be enough to dissuade a meta mob from hounding any given post with votes and flags.

Comment: This presumes that the meta effect is a bad thing, and that the extra attention is unwarranted.

Comment: @fbueckert : Do you personally think of it as bad/not desirable?

Comment: @fbueckert I'm aware. This is a proposal to avoid the meta effect, under the presumption that it is a bad thing. I personally don't hold a strong opinion on whether it is objectively good or bad.

Comment: @iLuvLogix I think there's some additional dogpiling that happens in the comments, which I think is unfortunate.  Voting, however, just brings additional eyes to it.  Generally, since those eyes come from the more quality minded members, it's going to be more critical.  It's less organic, but it's no less valid than sharing it on Facebook or Twitter.

Comment: @fbueckert I disagree with you on your point with 'more quality minded members' since access to meta is granted with reaching  a rep of 5..

Comment: @fbueckert But I agree with 'additional eyes'..

Comment: @iLuvLogix access isn't granted with 5 rep.  The privilege to ask a question comes when you have reached 5 rep points.  Access is granted to anyone.  But the "quality minded members" point is valid.  In general, the users that come to a SO question via a link in a meta post and the members who spent a lot of time on meta, which are the users who tend to be more interested in maintaining the quality standards.  That also means they are more likely to up/down vote and/or cast close or delete votes.

Comment: I could understand attempting to avoid meta-effect in votes. But in flags...? Why? What harm could "extra" flags bring?

Comment: @yivi admittedly I don't know how the flagging system works beyond "I raise a flag and it's usually marked as helpful by someone with more rep than me". "Hounding with close votes" might have been more accurate, idk. I guess my point is that people seem to be drawn to voting with the crowd - I know that if I see a post with lots of down-votes, I might be more inclined to look for reasons why it's off-topic rather than viewing it objectively like I would if I hadn't seen the voting (even subconsciously). Everyone does this in one way or another.

Comment: Again, I don't really have a hat in the ring here. This is just my two cents about a possible "solution" to it if you see it as an objectively negative effect.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley It's not even a good solution to that problem.  Finding the post is easy, so you're just making it more annoying for people to participate in the post, not stopping it, and when a specific post *is* being discussed on meta, often a screenshot wouldn't be enough.  People may need to be able to see not only the post, the comments, answers (if a question) the question (if an answer), the revision history, the post timeline, deleted content that the meta question author can't see, etc.

Comment: The *actual* solution is to either ask a meta question about a specific post, and link to it, or to ask a question *that is not about a specific post*, and that merely describes a hypothetical question (even if it's inspired by a real situation) and gets answers to that hypothetical question.  This both requires the meta question author to be able to accurately describe the situation clearly enough for meta users to understand it, and means any inaccuracies or incomplete info in the question may prevent the answer from being applicable to the situation it's based off of.

Comment: Also realize many questions *want* to have a meta effect.  Many questions are of the form, "I think this question shouldn't have been closed." or, "This is a good question it shouldn't be getting downvotes." and the *intention* of the author is for people to go there and vote on it.  People may then go there and see a bad, or close worth, or flag worthy, post and use those actions as they feel is appropriate, even if it's not what the meta author wanted to happen.

Comment: @Servy any information pertinent to a question should be included in that question, so standard users shouldn't _need_ to go to any given SO question in order to get what they want out of a question on Meta.

Comment: _In order to avoid the meta effect_, I proposed the above solution. Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough. If you _want_ the meta effect, by all means add a relevant link to the question. I'm not trying to propose a way to banish the meta effect as a whole. Perhaps this question is about avoiding the meta effect once and for all rather than on a case-by-case basis, in which case I mis-read the question.

Comment: For what it's worth, if an OP wants the meta effect to go one way and that backfires then I'm all for that. It makes entertaining reading for me while I'm on a break at work, and it teaches the OP about not trying to recruit meta to mass-upvote stuff.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Yes, pertinent details *should* be included in the question whenever possible.  But sometimes the author of the meta question can't access that information, sometimes they don't realize it's there, or that it's relevant.  Sometimes they're trying to mislead people into saying what they want them to say by not realizing there's additional context.  That's why having a link to a post, where people can see whatever context they want, is sometimes helpful.

Comment: I don't disagree, but unfortunately as soon as you link to a post you might feel the meta effect. Unless you implement solutions like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269191/8230810), it's unavoidable without abstracting away information which might lead people on meta to the relevant post.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Yes, it's *impossible* for certain types of meta questions to be asked without resulting in some form of meta effect.  That's just the reality of the situation.  So in effect your proposing that questions about a specific question either no longer be allowed to be posted, or make the quality (and resulting usefulness) of those posts *much* lower.  Even the solution you linked to doesn't avoid consequences of linking a post to meta, it just changes some of them.