Is the "Meta effect" good or bad?
For years, many people have said here on Meta that the so-called "Meta effect" is the reason why otherwise good (or at least decent) questions and answers might be down-voted.  It seems to me that this would discourage new users or low rep users from getting involved or asking questions, and I've seen a proposal to temporarily freeze votes on posts discussed on meta that would reduce its effects.
Overall, is the meta effect a good thing or a bad thing?

Can you give a (very brief) explanation of what you think the Meta effect is? (I ask because your question comes across as suggesting that "Meta effect" is an excuse for someone to vote a post down, instead of being an observed phenomenon.)

It's not pointless downvoting, the meta-effect is just a lot of eyes looking at a question, some of those resulting in potential up- and downvotes

If the questions or answers were good as you say, more people looking at them would result in upvotes, not downvotes. Maybe the issue is that they're not good to begin with?

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect

You're working with an incorrect assumption on what the Meta Effect is. It's just increased (critical) visibility.

I have not seen the meta effect used to explain (let alone justify) good content being downvoted.  I have seen it used to explain (but not justify, as such) why content that was only somewhat bad was downvoted as though it were absolutely atrocious.  Less commonly, I've also seen it as the explanation for upvotes, in a recent case sending a question to Hot Network Questions and earning the poster a good chunk of reputation.

This seems to me to be a duplicate of the question you linked suggesting a 24-hour freeze on voting.  This question consists of two seemingly rhetorical questions, a suggestion to implement that proposal, and then a suggestion that maybe other ideas might exist.  That really seems like it's essentially saying "that proposal should be implemented" - but you are of course welcome to edit the question to more clearly differentiate it and it can be reopened, as long as said explanation does not contain insults.

And if it's not about that proposal, [meta-tag:discussion] isn't a magic tag that prevents a unclear, unspecific or unanswerable question from being closed "just because is't a discussion.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377178/what-practical-and-reasonable-options-does-the-community-have-in-order-to-avoid

Nice answer on MSE related to this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392714/1059914

Really depends on which side of the aisle your seat is. Was How is Leetcode able to compile a C++ program without me writing a 'main()' function? really that important and helpful a question or did we just have people trying to cancel out each other's votes after the initial version of the question got an over-the-top negative response?

@user4581301 Probably paired with the fact that it is a question wrapped around a puzzle, making it very interesting. Important, no. Helpful... well it solves the puzzle. I'm sure plenty of people consider that to be in the realm of usefulness, especially since there is no standard definition for what is "useful" in this site. I can see how people would go to bat for a question like this.

You're working with an incorrect assumption on what the Meta Effect is. It's just increased (critical) visibility.
If that results in downvotes, then maybe the question wasn't "good".
If that results in upvotes, well, I've never seen someone complain about that, on Meta.
The effect in itself isn't inherently "good" or "bad".

It's becoming more and more obvious that a very small number of high reputation users are responsible for a large amount of what I'm talking about here.

That's a load of nonsense. If you're active at another hour, another set of users will be more active. Your activity now just happens to overlap with a few specific users that are also active at this moment.

If that results in downvotes, then maybe the question wasn't "good". True, but doesn't the number of downvotes come into play when the question ban is calculated? I guess nobody knows for sure how that is calculated, but I'd say that asking a question on meta about why your bad question is bad shouldn't be punished by ushering the asker into a question ban.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I can only answer speculation with speculation... Which is kinda pointless. We don't even know if that's a factor in question bans. Generally, asking on Meta why your question is bad, results in improvements to that question... Meta is often very willing to help improve a question if OP is willing to accept help.

The "Meta effect" is a terrible thing for Stack Overflow, because it brings a ton of attention to certain questions or answers that is almost entirely negative in nature, and steps should be taken to reduce it in my opinion.
Most of the users who browse Meta are either low-reputation users who are confused or upset about certain aspects of the platform (with low karma), or high-reputation users who tend to be overly critical and pedantic and in many cases almost seem to enjoy down-voting other users.
A temporary "freeze" on content/voting was proposed a decade ago, to help reduce the negative effects of participating in Meta,  and it was very popular:
Impose a 24 hour voting freeze on questions being discussed on Meta
To date, no action has been taken...
While it would be nice to imagine that every "vote" on this platform was done thoughtfully, by users who are fair-minded and follow all community guidelines, this is, in fact, wishful thinking and inaccurate and therefore the "Meta effect" greatly discourages participation, I believe, while having almost no positive or constructive purpose that I can think of currently.
Moreover, asking questions on Meta nearly always results in down-votes. This results in a sort of echo chamber among high-reputation users that are often very hostile to other users.

"asking questions on Meta nearly always results in down-votes" Assuming you mean receiving a net negative score, it does so less than half the time; the median Meta Stack Overflow question is upvoted.  is:q score:..-1 deleted:all: 36,625 results; is:q score:1.. deleted:all: 41,708 results

This highlights two circles which do exist on Meta, but are mischaracterized: 1) "either low-reputation users who are confused or upset about certain aspects of the platform" yes, users often come here when they find something unexpected while using the platform, which may be confusing or upsetting, but that it not entirely generalized to low-reputation users. Even long time users may also occasionally come here and find out that they had the wrong ideas all along.


"or high-reputation users who tend to be overly critical and pedantic and in many cases almost seem to enjoy down-voting other users" The veteran users regularly visiting Meta SO will more often than not have enough reputation for certain curation activities. They will also be familiar with how the site operates and have their mind set on how to best contribute to the repository, hence their strong opinions.


Now, the problem users face on Stack Overflow is what the expectations of the platform are. Criticism on SO is to be expected, both here and on the main site, especially when the same concern is raised hundreds of times without even trying to understand why things are the way they are. Such posts are inevitably downvoted because they do not constitute a positive contribution. There is simply no joy in downvoting yet another question from yet another misinformed user.

"Most of the users who browse Meta are either low-reputation users who are confused or upset" - no they don't browse meta. They just want to vent so they hit post immediately. I wish they would browse meta before posting unfounded accusations and assumptions, that would make things so much less sour.
