# Why was "Stack Overflow" chosen as a name for this site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-history

> As far I know Stack Overflow is the best site where technical/coding
>   related discussions are taking place.

Since I'm an addict to this site I wanted to know, *why this site was named as "Stack Overflow", because the first thing that came to our mind while thinking was that a "stack overflow" is a memory issues in the embedded C (mainly where memory constraints are limited).

Why did the site creators / owners adopt the name Stack Overflow? Is there any particular reason for this naming?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/help-name-our-website/

Comment: Good question - it still hasn't been correctly answered. I would also like to know what the name means.

Comment: @JaydenLawson - some (many) (most?) CPU's implement a "stack", which is an area of memory used for the storage of procedure arguments, variables, and function return values. This area of memory is limited in size, and when a program attempts to use more stack than is available a "stack overflow" error occurs. Thus, naming the site Stack Overflow is a bit of programmer-oriented humor, indicating that this is where programmers can go when *their* stack has overflowed - or, in other words, when they're out of ideas and need help. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis: I would not say CPU here.

Comment: If you're looking to create a website named after an error code, I'm pretty sure www.generalprotectionfault.com is still available.

Comment: FYI, stack overflow can happen in many languages, e.g. [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html).

Comment: Because stack underflow sounds underwhelming?

Comment: Because people wanted to make it hard to Google for actual stack overflow exceptions.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Why was Stack Overflow named Stack Overflow? Where does its money come from?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3857)

Comment: I searched and I cannot find out why the larger collection of sites was named StackEXCHANGE...? That is not really a computing concept. I suppose it was more understandable to non-programmers: exchange info?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

According to [Where do the names of the Stack Overflow trilogy sites come from?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61541/163250) and [Help Name Our Website](http://blog.codinghorror.com/help-name-our-website/), users voted on that name, from among this list:

> We've racked our collective brains, and this is the best we could do.
> We'd like your input to see if we're on the right track. Vote for the
> name that best embodies what you'd like to see on a software developer
> community website.
>
> - humbledeveloper.com
> - fellowhackers.com
> - gosub10.com or gosubten.com
> - writeoncereadmany.com
> - humbleprogrammers.com
> - privatevoid.com
> - cargocultdevs.com
> - dereferenced.com
> - bitoriented.com
> - algorithmical.com
> - corecursion.com
> - metaprogramming.com
> - stackoverflow.com
> - understandrecursion.com
> - shiftleft1.com

[As pointed out by Stijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266561/456814) (answer since deleted; 10k only), "stackoverflow.com" won with 25% of the votes.

Comment: Sure glad *privatevoid* wasn't chosen.  "humbledeveloper" would have been a blatant lie.  I sort of like "bitoriented".

Comment: You can also listen to [Stack Overflow podcast #1](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/podcast-1/) and hear Jeff and Joel talk about the name some more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters **Bring It On!** `:P` Many men have dared go toe to toe with my frosty sprinkled pastry goodness. None have succeeded `>:D`

Comment: @Cupcake: note that I already got 4 more since the last data dump update ;-P

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm way glad it wasn't named "bitoriented". That just sounds way too much like a bit-torrent site, especially when spoken.

Comment: My suggestion of HelpVampireCentralWithTagsInTitles.com was rejected :(

Comment: Some of the poll choices sound ridiculous, cargocultdevs.... seriously ? haha

Comment: understandrecursion.com would've been great... And fellowhackers.com has its own problems

Comment: Funny, I really rather like cargocultdevs. The world is full of people who copy and paste code, and often only have rather ridiculous mental models of what's going on.

Comment: @JonShemitz The world is full of them, but StackOverflow is a place where people get discouraged from doing that. ...At least, I hope it is.

Comment: @jpmc26 you put [too much faith](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8755199/456814) into mankind's willingness and ability to [apply critical thinking](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11384018/456814) in order to [save itself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266180/can-i-edit-an-answer-to-add-a-prevention-message-to-a-security-vulnerability#comment64516_266216).

Comment: how did algorithmical not win?

Comment: [fellowhackers...](http://akroot313.andrewkeir313.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/kids-exchange.jpg)

Comment: It's no suprise that some of the other options got so few votes.

Comment: @gitsitgo Given some of those suggestions, I'm pretty certain all the voters were hit by [a duck](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/122148/27881) without realizing it.  They weren't intended to be possibilities, but rather, pushed voters towards the one(s) he already wanted...

Comment: homeworkhelp.com

Comment: I think "bitoriented" would have been pretty cool.  That one is probably my favorite.

Comment: whathaveyoutried.com must be here...

Comment: Sorry but I will never accept that 'only hav[ing] rather ridiculous mental models of what's going on' is not an incredibly valuable skill.

Answer (score 15):

Some (many) (most?) CPU's implement a "stack", which is an area of memory used for the storage of procedure arguments, variables, and function return values. This area of memory is limited in size, and when a program attempts to use more stack than is available a "stack overflow" error occurs. Thus, naming the site Stack Overflow is a bit of programmer-oriented humor, indicating that this is where programmers can go when their stack has overflowed - or, in other words, when they're out of ideas and need help. Share and enjoy.

Comment: A few of the suggestions suffer from the same 'programmer-oriented humor', notably "dereferenced.com" and "writeoncereadmany.com". For the record, I'm happy with the current name. May your cup runneth over but your stack never overfloweth.