# Why is the website called 'Stack Overflow?'

Tags: discussion

I always wondered why 'Stack Overflow' is well, 'Stack Overflow' and I thought what a better way to find out than asking it on its own website.

Specifically what I wondered was if there's a link to the name, if there's some history or if it was just a random name. I know this is a pretty odd question, but it got me wondering.

Also to add, who were the original founders and why did they set up this website?

Comment: When I Google `Why is the website called 'Stack Overflow?'` I get a link to the answer (and plenty more background info to address your other question).

Comment: [Where do the names of the Stack Overflow trilogy sites come from?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61541/where-do-the-names-of-the-stack-overflow-trilogy-sites-come-from)

Comment: Ok, I see. It never came up for me as I was writing the question

Comment: Yeah, the internal search isn't as good as Google is - it's advisable to always check both

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was "Stack Overflow" chosen as a name for this site?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266557/why-was-stack-overflow-chosen-as-a-name-for-this-site)... Also, it was [definitely asked](http://web.archive.org/web/20100820131132/http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/61541/where-does-the-name-stack-overflow-come-from) before that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was the result of a poll held on the blog of one of the founders / owners:

https://blog.codinghorror.com/help-name-our-website/