# What can users do about outdated locked questions?

Tags: discussion, historical-lock, outdated-information, old-answers

When searching Google I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android) question. It's locked, stating 'historical significance'. That's a bit vague, and the description only references a problem with the question.

Nothing in the description mentions that the answers are very outdated and, for that reason, wrong. Inexperienced users may think the solutions are still valid, since nothing mentions there is a problem with the answer.
There is no way for me to comment, vote, or whatever. Only 'share', which is the last thing I want to do.

Comment: The recent cases of this that have popped up on meta have resulted in deletion.

Comment: That can probably be salvaged by editing out the part that asks where to find step-by-step instructions and deleting the one remaining link-only answer.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Every time I see you post now, it's like seeing a shirt with a missing button. It doesn't feel right.

Comment: @Mysticial: Someone should make a userscript to add in a hollow mod diamond after his username.

Comment: Maybe users should do nothing? It's locked, and so clear that it answers can't be made current. The dates on the question / answers can be used as a guide to how current their content is, just like any other question.

Comment: @MichalCharemza: I disagree. The date tells you how long ago the answer was written, but not how wrong or outdated it is. old ≠ outdated

Comment: If OP's linked question was posted today, it would very easily be closed as "too broad".

Comment: Why is that question closed in the first place? I'm certainly no expert on Android, but at first glance this question doesn't seem all that different from http://stackoverflow.com/q/236129/1157054, http://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/1157054, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1789945/1157054, etc to me. All highly upvoted, extremely useful questions for beginners asking how to do something relatively basic in their respective language.

Comment: @oldmud0 It's not that broad (although I have no doubt you'd find 5 trigger-happy closer-voters to consider it so). There are a number of ways to parse a JSON feed, yes, but the objective is quite clear and it's also narrowed down to a platform.

Comment: @Ajedi32 It's asking where to find step-by-step instructions on how to do X; if it just asked how to do X then it would probably be fine. We're a site that gives you the answer, we don't tell you where to find the answer, so we expect the questions to be geared towards that as well.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist So you're saying with a simple edit we could turn it into a perfectly valid question? In that case, let's do it. We just need someone to remove the lock first. https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=parse%20JSON%20is%3aquestion

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I'm not sure it's generally a good thing to be so pedantic about the phrasing of a question. Sure, it's asking for where to find a step by step guide, instead of getting the steps in an answer on how to do X, but in the end, it's quite clear the OP would welcome an answer that actually details what to do (instead of posting a link). You don't need to read that hard between the lines. Shutting down questions like that, despite the fact they've generated what looks like decent answers, is of no benefit to anyone.

Comment: @Bruno: That seems like the sort of edit the H&I-queue should be good for, at least on *new* questions...

Comment: @Bruno They asked why it was closed in the first place, and that's the only reason I can see that it may have been closed: it's asking for an off-site resource rather than just straight up asking the question. That's not a reason to completely shut it down with a lock, though, unless there was a lot of things happening with that post that are no longer on the revision history.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, [not that much happened](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9605913/revisions) between day 1 and closure/lock time (the very first version was really not great, but someone had tried to improve the question a little). There are a few deleted answers, but nothing catastrophic as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Bruno Right, there's nothing noticeable to suggest a lock was necessary/warranted. I guess we'd have to ask Bill the Lizard why he locked it, and there's a good chance he wouldn't even remember.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most users can't do anything about questions and answers under historical lock, besides raise a Meta question about it. Even high-rep users can't even raise any flags on them.

Historical locks are certainly one of the worst things on this Stack Overflow.

There are recurring questions on Meta about what to do with [so-called "outdated" answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265753/372643)<sup>(*)</sup> or [what to do with questions that also have potential security vulnerabilities](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266180/372643).

**The general idea on Stack Overflow is to be able to provide feedback on answers, using comments, downvotes or, as a last resort, edits when there is a problem. Historical locks go against all these principles.**

This leaves a couple of options:

- Deletion, which can be a bit of a shame, since some of these Q&A have potentially interesting information, even if they don't fit the current rules (remember that SO and its rules have changed over the years).
- Re-opening, or at least removing the lock.

(I'll make a potentially controversial suggestion here: simply re-open, but create a new banner that says "*This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here*". With this, we might even be able to add new answers in case there are other ways to achieve the goal suggested in the question.)

To be more specific about [the question you're talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9605913/372643), I'm not quite sure why this was locked or why this was off-topic. The question itself is indeed phrased as a query for external resources, as opposed to direct answers. Yet, it has quite clearly attracted direct answers to a problem that's reasonably clear. I think closure should be evaluated based on whether the whole Q&A makes sense, even if the question itself is a bit wobbly, more so when it happens a year after the question has been asked. If anything, this Q&A looks pretty much like a canonical question in many ways (and canonical questions seem to be the ideal the most fervent curators on this site seem to aim for).

<sub>(*) I think "outdated" is relative: it can be useful to some readers to find out how something was done using a version that's not the latest, typically when they're unable to use the latest version.</sub>

Comment: "Historical locks are certainly one of the worst things on this Stack Overflow." I'm sure both sides will concurr, one side saying "Yes, it should be deleted" and the other side "Yes, it has upvotes and thus is valuable, it must be open".

Comment: @Deduplicator I think my main point was that historical locks should never be used at all (and the feature should no longer exist). I would also tend to err on the latter side: if the question has generated a sufficiently good Q&A as a whole, leave it be (especially after a year or so): no one needs find *all* the questions on SO to their taste. There's many other types of questions to fight against (e.g. very low quality, open ended questions, questions lacking any relevant details, ...). "Off-topic" is itself too broad a label anyway.

Comment: The *worst* thing on SO was the insane amounts of unproductive drama surrounding things like "What's your favorite programmer cartoon?" Drama that dragged on for *years* with no sign of an end. Historical locks are merely second-to-the-worst.