# Top-voted answer is dangerous, hiding safer answer

Tags: discussion, edits, community-wiki

Consider [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git/1628584#1628584).

The accepted – and highly voted – community wiki answer works, but is a bit dangerous, as one may easily lose data. The second and third most-voted answers are essentially variations of this answer.

[The #4 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22654961/49793) provides a simpler and less dangerous solution. However, many users won't read that far, and therefore go for the more risky solution.

[How to deal with dangerous answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276496/how-to-deal-with-dangerous-answers) suggests to leave it to voting. However, I think the chance that the "safe" answer will bubble to the top are pretty slim in this case. Due to having been written much earlier, the "dangerous" answers have a huge head-start in the number of votes. Also, the "safe" answer doesn't really attract votes, as it lacks explanations, and is a bit confusing (it starts with a somewhat uncommon solution, the better solution is "tacked" on as update).

How can we address this, so that people don't run into the dangerous answer anymore? Would it be OK to add a warning at the top of the community wiki answer, with a link to the safer answer?

Comment: Can you give a few details of what specifically is dangerous about that answer? I'm not really familiar enough with the technology to know.

Comment: Doesn't really sound grave enough to warrant intervention / editing / etc. There's a bunch of warning comments on the first answer already. A question-comment might be least obtrusive. (And anyway, haven't you voided your warranty by definition when using git?)

Comment: There are warnings there, but yes someone who quickly skims the text, copypastes the commands and run them can get a nasty surprise.

Comment: If you have uncommitted changes, they will be lost (See the comment on line #2)

Comment: Whoa, why the downvotes?

Comment: No idea, I think it's a perfectly reasonable thing to discuss. I guess some people have seen a lot of "old answer is much higher voted than newer more correct answer" posts before maybe but I don't really feel that this is one of those.

Comment: May be a comment discussion on that answer might be a better point staring out?

Comment: @ivarni someone who quickly skims the text and then runs some random code found on the internet without paying attention *deserves* the nasty surprise he'll get. :-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I don't think anyone who does that nessescarily *deserves* the surprise they'll get, but the real question is if adding even more warnings are really going to stop them from shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ On which answer would you put the discussion? There are already lots of comments on the dangerous answer. There was even a comment that suggested the safe solution, but it too got lost in the deluge. Comments on the safe answer could help improve it, but would this be enough to change the situation?

Comment: @oefe The only data you could lose would be uncommitted changes. Which he explicitly mentions next to the command that does it (the reset). I don't see the problem here..?

Comment: @oefe remember that meta votes are different than main-site votes.

Comment: Actually I have somewhat a similar issue.  I notice when there's an upvote on my answer, there's a comment, but it has been downvoted with no comments either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569522/hibernate-or-eclipselink/10975532?noredirect=1#comment50111512_10975532

Comment: [This is another Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android) that the top answer isn't the best (and even seems to be wrong), but I tend to agree with the others: Users have to do the research themselves to find the best answers.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski what a rediculous thing to say! Some people are not quite as intelligent as others and will just follow instructions given by "experienced" people and places their trust in these "experts". Don't forget many people come here because they just don't have a clue or even have the brain power to know better. Be nice!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The answer is a Community Wiki, meaning that anyone is allowed and encouraged to edit the answer further.

If the answer *works*, but is missing a warning, then edit the warning in.  That's all there is to it.

I would discourage referencing another answer or saying, "This is too dangerous, look over here", or anything of that sort; this answer has worked for a lot of other users (and the OP in their specific case), and I wish to leave the burden of research and discovery to the reader.  They may see all of the high numbers and think that this is the *best* solution, but I would hope that they would keep looking at their scenario and the answers that best match for themselves.

Comment: though it looks like it is only CW as it got auto converted under the old rules rather than any explicit desire to encourage third party edits.

Comment: @MartinSmith:  Be that as it may, the answer is *still* CW.

Answer (score 18):

> the "safe" answer doesn't really attract votes, as it lacks explanations, and is a bit confusing

I think it would be heavy-handed to edit other (non-community wiki) answers, but it's clearly OK for you to improve the "safe" answer. Add explanation, clean up confusion, etc. It doesn't *deserve* to be the top-voted answer if even its advocates think it's confusing. Make it better, and it'll get more votes!

If the "safe" answer is beyond saving, you can always write your own answer with all the issues clearly explained. At the end of the day all you can do is share your knowledge and advice and let the community decide how useful it is.

Comment: `I think it would be heavy-handed to edit other answers` presumably you mean editing them to add additional explanations.  You'd be quite right normally, but the answer is a Community Wiki.  The whole point of making an answer CW is for the author to indicate that the work is not their own, that it is a collaboration of many user's content, and to say that future readers are welcome to edit the post *in ways that actually change the content of the answer*, such as to add an explanation of what's going on.  So in this (rare) case, such an edit would actually be okay.

Comment: @Servy I clarified I'm not referring to the community wiki answer.  That said,  I worry that it's heavy-handed to edit highly voted answers and change their meaning; even if you think you're doing the right thing.  You'll never go wrong making a good answer better, but editing the intention and meaning of an answer you think is wrong is clearly riskier.

Comment: An edit to indicate potential consequences of the actions being taken is going to be completely fine.  An edit that just changes the answer to suggest a completely different approach would likely be a problem, yes.

Comment: There is a limit to the amount of changes in an edit, often not enough to add a whole explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This comes up every so often, one guy thinking he's somehow better than all the other voters (in this case, just shy of *two thousand* of them!) and should have some magic power to nuke someone else's content. That's why you're getting downvotes yourself.

**If you think the answer is that dangerous, comment the author to write a disclaimer on it.**

You may even be right! But you may be wrong, and that's something that you don't seem to have considered, nor the fact that this is the entire purpose of the voting system in the first place.

Comment: Now you are getting the downvotes...See the awkwardness..

Comment: @JishnuPrathap: I don't mind. The truth hurts, after all. :) And I got upvotes too.

Comment: And yet you call your answer the truth though it contradicts the other answers that actually did get higher votes. You think your answer which was not highly upvoted is THE RIGHT ANSWER. And anyone downvoting it just hates the truth. Physician, heal thyself.

Comment: @trlkly https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/bandwagon

Comment: Then so is yours. I only used your own logic against you. You're the one arguing that the OP is probably wrong because the answer was highly upvoted. You're the one who acts as if the number of votes correlates with truth. That's the bandwagon fallacy. Just because I wasn't a big enough jerk to use that easily refuted site (as it misuses the concept of fallacies as refutations, allowing you to always link to https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/the-fallacy-fallacy). This is why I'm happy I realized that high rep need not correlate with high ability. (check my history for a meta post about that.)

Comment: Still, the fact that this site is built on the bandwagon fallacy and apparently has no mechanism to get wrong answers fixed (I assumed that we could report them and show factual information for why it's wrong) makes me worried that the site is going to break down. The only reason I'm even reading this post is because I was trying to figure out how to handle a post based on an erroneous jspref test that 500 people didn't realize was messed up, leading to a top answer that is 100% wrong--as proven by facts (showing the flaw), not upvotes.

Comment: And the only reason I'm commenting is that there is no mechanism to fix what you're doing but to comment. And you've just shown how contacting the author of a post doesn't necessarily fix the problem. People who write their answers think they're right, and there's no incentive to fix a highly voted wrong answer, as a downvote will barely affect you. (And sorry for three posts, but long arguments can take more space. Again, why there should be another mechanism to deal with this stuff.)

Comment: @trlkly: _"You're the one arguing that the OP is probably wrong because the answer was highly upvoted."_ I never said anything like that. If you're going to jump on a year-old post just to whine and complain, at least get your facts straight.