# What should I do with this history question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I've cross the path of this question: [What was the first programming language with Enumerations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32995508/2307070) which, at least to me, doesn't fit in the SO guideline How To Ask since it's a question about history of programming languages.

I can't find any close reason that describe why I want to close it.

Two questions:

1. Should it be closed?
2. If so, what would be the correct way to close it?

Comment: I would say it is just off topic because it doesn't really have anything to do with programming and solving a problem.

Comment: @JoeW is *have* to do with programming, since it's about the history of programming... :/

Comment: It's not a "practical" or "specific" programming problem right?

Comment: I find knowledge of the history of programming languages practical, albeit not in the same sort of direct way that e.g. knowledge of regular expressions is practical. I sometimes learn about approaches to problems that I wouldn't have otherwise thought of.

Comment: @JohnColeman How does knowing what language did it first help you? If you are talking about something that was first used 50 years ago chances are it won't provide a lot of use in today's world. Even if it did you would get more information from a question that asks what languages utilize a feature rather then what language did it first. Also you need to consider that when it comes to which language did it first it is somewhat opinion based as small obscure languages may be considered debatable if they count for first use.

Comment: @JoeW I guess that in this particular case such knowledge is unlikely to help. My comment was mostly a defense of the utility of studying the history of programming languages. I wouldn't want to say that history questions are off-topic per-se. Then again -- I tend to have the free-for-all notion of open discussion from the early days of UseNet. The entire idea of censoring an interesting question strikes me as misguided. There is enough on-topic tripe on SO that I see little point in targeting technically off-topic but tangentially related good questions

Comment: I understand why it was closed and suspected that it may or may not be well received due to its nature. This is a great community and I'll try to keep my questions more on-topic. +1

Comment: @JohnColeman I share your distaste at closing well-written, clear, answerable questions that happen to be out of scope, and it's why I didn't vote on this. If I'd come across this personally, I'd have turned a blind eye.

Comment: Whatever close reason might've been appropriate for this question, it's ended up closed as 'Too Broad', which - for an objective, factual question that shouldn't need more than a paragraph or two to fully answer - seems plainly absurd.

Comment: @MarkAmery that's why I raised the question here

Comment: @Thomas it seems to me that a custom off-topic reason along the lines of *"Questions purely about programming history that have no possible practical use to a programmer are off-topic on Stack Overflow."* would've been the only reasonable way to vote to close this, but by the looks of it not one of the close voters took that approach.

Comment: Checked the help center, didn't see anything about trivia questions being on topic.  Which is a shame, because I *love* me some trivia.

Comment: It's on-topic on [programmers.se]: [Is programming history on topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/is-programming-history-on-topic)

Comment: @Deduplicator are you sure? The post you've linked to specifies a "no trivia" clause, which arguably rules this question out. Like Will, I'd really *like* this question be on-topic somewhere in the network - I'm just not convinced that it is.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Well, I retract and repent. On looking again, yes, it uns afool of the trivia-barrier.

Comment: @JohnColeman Relevant to the 'history has practical importance' argument: an example of (what turns out to be) an obscure history question whose [true answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31235907/1709587) can only be found by delving into old bug reports but which has clear practical importance to a PHP programmer trying to understand the warnings in their error log: http://stackoverflow.com/q/999066/1709587

Comment: @pnuts true. But I didn't even knew what to put in the message and if it should be closed

Comment: It could be marked off topic. A programming language is a tool used during the process of programming, it's not programming itself. Since the question is not related to 'how to use', or 'this doesn't work' or something similar, it's only related to the programming language, not to programming itself.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164436/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-objective-questions-asked-out-of-curiosity

Comment: The accepted answer is based on the Wikipedia page for "Enumerated type". If the answer is so readily available eslewhere, there's probably no reason to keep it on SO.

Comment: @m69 then there is no reason to keep [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/948135/2307070) but it have 1185 upvotes...

Comment: @Thomas The question "how do I write statement X in language Y" doesn't show any research effort and is probably answered by any form of documentation about the language, so it would run the risk of being closed if it were asked today. Maybe the Ruby documentation was sketchy back in 2009? The number of upvotes doesn't really make it a better question.

Answer (score 15):

I think the strongest reasons to close questions, in order of descending importance, are as follows:

1. The question helps no-one, not even the poster (e.g. because it’s so broad or so narrow that it’ll never get an answer ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995677/how-to-get-started-using-opos)).
2. The question helps only the poster because it is based on wrong assumptions and only serves to weed these out ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134655/difference-between-length-and-fnlength-in-jsp-el)).
3. The question helps only the poster because it (inadvertently) asks for the solution to multiple problems at once and is thus very unlikely to help any future visitor ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995056/mysql-php-script-with-an-array-thats-not-being-called-and-returning-null)).
4. The question has already been answered elsewhere on the site (or on other stack exchange sites) and no answers provide new insight into the problem.
5. The question is badly suited to a Q&A format because it is opinion-based.
6. The question is so completely unrelated to the subject matter of the site that they’re going after the completely wrong audience.

Questions of type #2, #3 and #4 are especially problematic if they begin showing up as “noise” in the results to completely unrelated searches and prevent people with actual problems from getting answers quickly. Noisy search results also drive people to ask duplicate questions because they didn’t find the canonical answer first.

Personally, I’ve been hesitant to hand out close votes for questions that are just a little-bit off-topic. Typically, such questions are specific enough that they don’t have the problem of adding noise to search results – and if they do, that can easily be mitigated by wording the title as unambiguously as possible.

So, no, I wouldn’t close the post in question because I can see no downsides to allowing such (slightly off-topic) question and see no reason to close solely on the basis of principle.

Comment: IMHO It should *not* be closed but instead *moved* to programmers http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @burzum Yes of course, if the question finds a better audience on another site, moving it is a good idea. However, the audience of stack overflow is just so much larger than that of other stack exchange sites that it might make sense to keep the question anyway.

Comment: I would add to the 4-th point: the issue with duplicate questions remaining open is that new answers _are or will be_ worse than answers to the original question.

Comment: Perhaps the CS stackexchange (I don't remember the link).  This could be of interest to theoretical computer science (history can be important there ... for answering why things are as they are).

Answer (score -4):

This question serves no purpose other than to entertain the user.  Will the fact that LanguageX was the first to implement a particular type change how the user writes their code?  Is it trying to solving a problem?  Is it practical?

If it is on-topic over on Programmers and is a good enough question to save, move it there.  If not, it should be closed with a custom reason like "this is a question about the history of programming, not an actual programming related issue".

Comment: You seem to be advocating for closing solely on the basis of principle (“the question does not belong here”). Why is it important that this question be closed? Whom is it hurting?

Comment: Because we close questions that are not on-topic?  From the help center: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."  There is nothing practical about this question, it's not going to solve any problems (unless you count "being able to answer mindless trivia questions" as an actual problem).  While the question at hand has a singular answer, it isn't going to help anyone solve any problems.

Comment: Now you have explained where the principle comes from but I still don’t know why it’s important that this principle be applied to this case.

Comment: Don’t get me wrong, I can see the value of applying this principle to other cases. E.g.: If you’re asking a practical question out of pure curiosity then it may be a problem whose solution you can’t test right now and you might not be able to weed out wrong answers, hurting others who might be looking for a solution because they DO face the problem. But here, the question isn’t only not of a practical nature to the OP, it’s of no practical value to anyone. So a wrong answer can’t hurt anyone.

Comment: It is not the OP's job to weed out wrong (or [dangerous](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276496/how-to-deal-with-dangerous-answers)) answers.  Quite often, they are not qualified to do so.  If the question is of no particular value to anyone, why is it our job to keep it around?  It's just here sucking up bandwidth and distracting users from more practical problems that are of value to *someone*.

Comment: The OP’s job is to mark the answer that worked for them as accepted. If the OP didn’t actually face the problem they’ve described, it may not be possible for them to recognize a flawed answer.
Also I said “no practical value”, not “no value at all”: Many things have value for some people even if they’re never of a practical use. I might find knowing which programming language first had enums valuable even if I never plan to travel back in time to program something with enums.
When you accuse a question of “sucking up bandwidth”, what kind of bandwidth are you talking about?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want this question closed because you find it distracting for other users. This goes deeper than mere principle but I’m still not sure it’s a valid reason. Is it really the job of moderators to define what has value and what hasn’t and what is distracting to others and what isn’t? Maybe it depends on how off-topic it is and how often it pops up in the wrong places, no? And maybe the solution to popping up in the wrong places is not something moderators should fix by closing but by re-wording.

Comment: "This question serves no purpose other than to entertain the user". Entertain or educate? Is a history student being entertained? There's nothing wrong with wanting to learn more about a topic. Learning more about how something came to be can help your overall understanding of a concept.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Not everything programming related is on-topic here on SO (that's why we have other SE sites like Programmers, Code Review, Computer Science, Software Recs, etc.).  "Which language was the first to do X" is about as unproductive of a history question as I can imagine on a site who's goal is to "solve practical problems".

Comment: That's completely besides the point of my comment. I've already conceded (my comment to OP) that my question maybe didn't belong there. My point is that its absurd and rude for you to make a claim that I was somehow seeking entertainment. No friend, I asked the question because I was learning about enums that week and, in my experience, learning how something came to be can reveal deeper details on how its to be used.