# Should answers that are "just for fun" or encourage poor or dangerous practices, be called-out?

Tags: discussion, answers

Please refer to this question, and in particular its answers:

[How can I efficiently remove elements by index from a very large list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63495264/how-can-i-efficiently-remove-elements-by-index-from-a-very-large-list)

It seems like this question has been treated rather as a Code Golf-style challenge, with the result that answers are being benchmarked against each other and the fastest one is the "winner". That in and of itself is not an issue, but at the time of this writing [the fastest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63496256/70345) is one that uses reflection to get at the internals of the `List<T>` class to mutate its internal elements.

Anyone who knows enough about C# knows that answer is unsafe and should almost certainly not be used in production code. But anyone who knows that is a professional and/or enthusiast programmer, not a copy-paste-driven developer whose only goal is to find the answer to their particular problem of "how to make list removal go brrr", without considering the consequences. And the consequences of using an answer that depends on an internal implementation that could change at any time are liable to be pretty painful, should said implementation change<sup>1</sup>.

**Do we care? Should we care? Is it our duty as responsible programmers, and/or Stack Overflow's as a repository of programming knowledge, to decorate appropriate pitfalls with "here be dragons"?**

I personally believe it is not - buyer beware and all that, especially when you're getting something for nothing - but I'm interested to hear what Meta thinks on the subject.

<sup>1 Microsoft almost certainly isn't going to change this implementation anytime soon, but that's not the point - the answer is merely an example of code that could be considered harmful.</sup>

Comment: write a comment under each unsafe approach, why it is unsafe or link to an answer. besides downvoting it is the only thing you can do

Comment: It is not unsafe at all.  It is a much smarter way to do what the highly upvoted answer did.  Thanks for giving me the cue to upvote a post from a clever programmer sharing his insights, that doesn't happen enough anymore.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276496/792066

Comment: I am the author of the dangerous answer. I hesitated to post this answer, but no answer explained why the OP code is slow and the gain perf/memory is just too high to be ignored. But I totally agree, I miss a notion to indicate this is dangerous. Thank to help me to improve my answer.