# Is a comment warning enough when dealing with potential data loss?

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I suggested an edit to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28778358/19927) I consider dangerous, and it was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9635569) with the reason

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

The answer suggests using a potentially destructive windows command to update one's PATH: `SETX`. This command [truncates the PATH's value to the first 1024 characters](https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx), from which there is no easy recovery. The answer does mention a limit on path size, but offhandedly and without a disclaimer about data loss.

I added a comment with the warning but, in my opinion, the potential for data loss warrants editing the answer with a disclaimer. I think a comment warning is too easy to miss. Luckily, I saved my PATH before trying `SETX` out, but other people have [been](https://superuser.com/questions/812754/how-to-recover-from-path-being-truncated-to-1028-characters-by-setx) [bitten](https://github.com/joe-niland/bedrock-windows/issues/1) by `SETX`'s truncating. I know it would have ruined my day.

I looked elsewhere on MSO to see what the consensus is. From a [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266180/can-i-edit-an-answer-to-add-a-prevention-message-to-a-security-vulnerability), [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266216/19927) seems to be similar to my opinion on the issue, and in the answer to another question it links to about [`git reset --hard` and data loss warnings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266022/how-do-i-deal-with-answers-that-are-good-for-experienced-users-but-potentially-d), the answerer edited warnings into dangerous answers.

Occasions when editing someone's answer is not a good idea, like when [adding information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265689/should-i-accept-an-edit-that-adds-information-to-an-answer), doesn't seem to be this case. The solution stays the same, except for the warning of a possible dangerous outcome.

Have I incorrectly gauged the community's stance on edits like this?

Comment: Whenever you make big edits like this, it's iffy... what was your edit summary for this?

Comment: It's probably better writing your own answer, and refer to the other one. And of course a comment might do as well, including that the answerer is pinged regarding your concerns.

Comment: A comment should probably be sufficient.  If someone is just going to copy code from the internet and run it blindly without reading, I don't feel terribly bad for them.

Comment: @Patrice When you say "big edit" do you mean character count? The answer isn't changed, only the dangerous effects are warned of. The summary was _"Add warning about dangerous SETX behaviour: it truncates PATH to first 1024 characters"_

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ the answer has 49 votes already, any new answer would stay at the bottom for the foreseeable future, possibly forever. My goal with the edit is for it to be seen and prevent people from truncating their PATH, I see a comment as a much better option than a new answer, but even that falls short in my opinion.

Comment: @bobesponja Combine both, comment and answer, if the full aspects don't fit in a comment.

Comment: Looks like there is an answer on that post which also addresses your concern: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30644449/4771017

Comment: @Becuzz The point is that even people who diligently read the answer will be bitten. It only mentions, offhandedly, that _"[...] it has limits like path size"_. What does "limits" mean? I would expect it to mean the command would error out, rather than truncate my data.

Comment: Did you try and contact the author?  It says they were on 18 minutes ago.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure I understand what you mean by combining both comment and answer, could you elaborate? I can't make the edit outright, hence this question to discuss dangerous-answer editing.

Comment: I rather think a better view would be that such a visible answer should be as complete as possible, @Becuzz.

Comment: @bobesponja You could leave a comment on the suspected answer, referring to your answer, to attract more attention.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I understand now. My goal with asking this question on MSO was to discuss whether comments are enough in cases like this, where irreversible data loss can occur. Adding an answer and commenting on the original answer linking to my answer doesn't address that, in my opinion.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the suggestion, I was going to do that and forgot.

Comment: @bobesponja I am all for protecting people from doing dumb things they don't know are dumb.  But as the saying goes, make it idiot proof and the universe will come along with a better idiot.  Someone *will* screw it up no matter how many comments, warnings or skull and crossbone stickers we put on it.  As long as the information is there, you have done your duty.  It is the reader's responsibility to, well, read.  I commend your desire to help, but at some point you have to realize that you can't save everyone from themselves.

Comment: Am I the only one annoyed by the fact that this question is off topic, yet nobody as mentioned this or VTC?

Comment: How is it off topic?

Answer (score 11):

I agree with Kevin B. If I saw an edit such as yours, I would flag it as vandalism. Even if your edit is true, the way you have presented it is essentially:

> THIS ANSWER IS BAD! DO NOT USE!

Which is obviously wrong. More appropriate would be one or more of these options:

- Comment
- Downvote
- Add your own answer
- [Suggest] edit so that it is a (non bold, matter of fact, non any emphasis) disclaimer at the end rather that a bright neon sign at the beginning.

You want to say someone is wrong? Great, this community thrives on having the most correct information, but do it in a respectful way.

Comment: I'm surprised it came across that way, it wasn't my intention at all. If I'd thought the answer was inherently bad, I would have just downvoted it. The only issue I have with the answer is the hidden potential for data loss; it works well, except when the PATH is too long. I'll either go for a comment in the future or a non-emphasised disclaimer at the end. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: // , @StevenPenny, if you're going to flag an answer as vandalism, it had better be for better reasons than the sort that start with "the way you have presented it...". Perhaps consider how you come across, too.

Answer (score -2):

#### Yes, a comment warning is plenty.

If you feel the answer is not useful because it's missing that information, downvote it. If you want to provide an answer that does include that information, do so. But do not add a warning like this to an existing answer; if the owner of that answer feels it is important enough, they can add it themselves.

This kind of warning is in a way an attack against the answer because you're basically saying the answer is dangerous and shouldn't be used or should be used with caution. That is in fact your intent, but it's akin to saying the answer is wrong, which is not what edits by users other than the op are for.

Comment: A banner like bob esponja tried to add is over the top, but I don't think a single sentence -- in normal styling -- with this rather important detail would be in serious conflict with the author's intent.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying the answer can be dangerous and should be used with caution, and I explain how to eliminate the risk. In my opinion that is not akin to saying the answer is wrong, nor attacking it, it's akin to improving the answer by letting people know of the hidden danger and how to avoid it. The goal of SO is to have correct, up-to-date information. As @JoshCaswell and Steven Penny say, the banner was probably excessive and I'll keep that in mind. Potential data loss causes that reaction in me, especially when I find it in a highly voted answer on SO. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: // , 
More than once have I come across buried comment warnings about horrors that I would never have seen in an answer, especially for languages or operating systems I'm not yet familiar with.

It's at the point, now, where I feel like I _must_ read the comments, just in case.